Vue Table Component adding a "line break" in the header title and checkbox
title is self explanatory, is there any way to add a linebreak to the checkbox and the title on the header? (also for specific reasons I cannot add in js or custom css)
im using the primevue documents as my reference but there seems to be no guide on my specific issue: https://primevue.org/datatable/
Code:
<Column header="Check" field="bCheck" :rowspan="2" selection-mode="multiple">

My investigation is that using the inspect element, I am able to adjust the spacing but it is only because it is "inside" the <Column header> since this is a Vue datable and it is already done for you
so my goal is is to go from: (below are just mockups)
check[]

to:
check
 [] 


Hello, was my answer what you were looking for? If not, I'd be happy to help you find a solution to the issue.

Yes you can - the docs don't make it super obvious, but Column has a slot for the header:
<Column>
  <template #header>
    <!-- place whatever you'd like to show in the header here -->
  </template>
</Column>

